# Quit Mathematica script (no matter what)

Tags: parallelization, kernel, scripting, external-calls

I have a complicated script (not just written by me) that gets called using `MathKernel -script script.m`. Among others `script.m` uses parallel subkernels and external calls through `RunProcess` and `OpenRead["!"<>cmd]`. I sometimes encounter a situation where all lines until `Quit` get run yet the task never completes. So something of the form

```
lotsOfCode
...
Print["We arrived at Quit"];
Quit[]
```

Here `"We arrived at Quit"` will print but the task will never `Quit`. `lotsOfCode` should be viewed as a black box. What could be preventing the script from terminating? How can I really Quit?

---

System: Linux, Mathematica 11.1 (and 12.1)

I am happy with a linux based solution so I'm thinking I should probably invoke something like `kill` through something like `RunProcess` in order to get Mathematica to kill itself. A cleaner Mathematica based solution that figures out what is preventing it from quiting would of course be nicer.

---

This [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145070/how-can-i-terminate-a-mathkernel-that-is-running-an-external-program-after-a-tim) seems related though it is looking for a different type of solution.

Comment: A minimal example of code that has this problem would help.

Comment: @JohnDoty, I understand. If I can find one I will of course add it. Note that it is something that a.) Does not occur reliable, i.e. the same code can sometimes have this halting behaviour and other times not. b.) I find it in this big code and have not yet reproduced it in something compact. So for now I would appreciate it if the question could focus on what could possibly make Quit[] fail. Of course I understand that this makes the question more difficult to answer. In the linked question a minimal example with a function called sleepy is constructed. Perhaps that one can be kept in mind.

Comment: `Quit` should never be necessary in a script.

Comment: Taking `Quit` out gives the same hanging result. `Quit` is there to emphasize that the very last line just before it got reached and yet the script did not terminate.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I don't think it solves the issue as it actually initially occurred without any explicit `Quit` present but are you saying that `Quit` would not work? (As in act as `Abort[]` to finish the computation so that the script terminates.)

Comment: No, it would not solve it, I should have made it clear. `Quit` is simply redundant.

Comment: Right, but it is not always redundant right? If I were to use it in some branch like I could use `Abort` in some branch it would still terminate the script at that moment, even if other command follow it. Or not?

Comment: I've seen plenty of flaky behaviour from parallel calculations, but I don't think people will be able to say much here without a minimal example. Can you try to create one?  I understand that you don't want to do it if avoidable because it is a lot of work, and are hoping for a hint. I don't have any idea, unfortunately. I have not experienced this specific mode of failure yet.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks, I will see what I can do. I think the part of the question about a `Quit` that works no matter what could be answerable without figuring out what was causing the problem. I might answer myself when I work it out. I would think that something like killing all created WolframKernels on the system level might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that replacing `Quit[]` with `CloseKernels[]; Pause[5]; Quit[]` solves the issue as pointed out in a comment to [a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124667/wolframscript-never-exits-v11-only).